# Is every metric on a topological two-sphere bi-Lipschitz equivalent to the standard metric?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Is every metric on a topological two-sphere bi-Lipschitz equivalent to the standard metric?

I was thinking of the easier case of an arc, thinking that the graph of $\sqrt{x}$ from 0 to 1 is not bi-Lipschitz equivalent to $[0,1]$ because od the singularity, but then I realized that only the standard projection failed to be bi-Lipschitz, and another map (baed on arclength) would probably make them equivalent.

Comment: A function being bi-Lipschitz means the function and its inverse are Lipschitz.

Answer (score 2):

This is false even if you relax "bi-Lipschitz" to "quasi-symmetric" and your example is a good one. In fact, there is by now a substantial literature on quasi-symmetric "uniformization" of metrics on 2-spheres, see [here](http://math.nyu.edu/~bkleiner/icm.pdf) and [here](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~mbonk/icm.pdf) for (somewhat outdated) references.